# Adding a simple counter[i] variable in JavaScript to append to a wrapper.append(container);

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, append, wrapper

Here is the current app: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MattNewtonian/r3509dqg/)
It currently spits out 31 semi-random but not duplicate entries like this:

```
meal1= undefined,
Plain Pizza,
Hard-boiled egg,
Gluten-free cookie,

meal2= undefined,
Fried Beefcake,
Hard-boiled egg,
Graham Crackers,

meal3= undefined,
Lasagna,
Tater tots,
Sundae,
```

**See where it says "Undefined"? I'm trying to add a sort of day[i] counter to it, which requires (I think) appending another datatype to the container div.

I'm having a lot of trouble adding an additional variable that plays by these rules.

What I've tried:
Nesting a for loop that would increment the day per entry, and append that as a new div at  the bottom of the script:

```
var i = 1;
var day = [];
for (i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
    return day[i] (I don't know...)
}
```

This doesn't work and breaks the code every time. Since I am learning, can you provide a few types of syntax I could experiment with to solve this? If you want to just fix it, that's fine, too. I just want to learn *why* some of this stuff works.

At the bottom of the Javascript code we have:

```
for (var key in meals){
    container = $('<div id="mealsDiv" class="container"></div>');
    wrapper.append(container);

    //This is where I want to add an extra div class that shows the date (1-31). 

    //I want to append day[i] to the meal and just number them, 1-31. 

    //I tried doing the following but it just breaks everything. 

    container.append('<div class="date">' + day[i] +'</div>');
    container.append('<div class="main">' + meals[key].main +'</div>');
    container.append('<div class="side">' + meals[key].side +'</div>');
    container.append('<div class="dessert">' + meals[key].dessert +'</div>');
}
```

Comment: `return i`? what do you think that is doing? You are trying to increment `i` by one? Add one to i, no loop. And if `day[i]` is returning undefined, than not sure what is in `day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the `undefined` because `day` is a number not an array and you're trying to do `day[i]`

```
var day = 1;
console.log(x[1]); // undefined
```

You can simply use the `key` which is the index of the meal like :

```
container.append('<div class="date">' + (+key + 1) +'</div>');
```

the `+key` is to to cast it to an `int` and `+ 1` is because the array index starts from `0`

instead of

```
container.append('<div class="date">' + day[i] +'</div>');
```

here's your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mpeq1zyk/)

Comment: Holy smokes I didn't know I could do that! Thank you!!